# Python3 + Pillow + QT5: Crash when I resize a label containing an image

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, python-imaging-library

I'm getting a message box: "Python has stopped working" when I load an image into a QLabel in a window that is already visible. Selecting debug shows: an unhandled Win32 exception occurred in Python.exe.

If I load the image into the label before showing the window, it displays correctly.

Here's the stripped down code:

```
#!/usr/bin/etc python
import sys
import os
import stat
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PIL import *
from PIL.ImageQt import *

def update(label):
    filename = r"C:\Users\me\Pictures\images\00000229.jpg"
    im1 = Image.open(filename)
    print ("Read ({},{})".format(im1.width, im1.height))
    im2 = im1.rotate(90, expand=True)
    print("Rotate ({},{})".format(im2.width, im2.height))

    im2.thumbnail((1200,1200))
    print("Thumbnail({},{})".format(im2.width, im2.height))

    qimage = ImageQt(im2)
    pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(qimage)
    label.setPixmap(pixmap)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

desktop = QDesktopWidget()
deskGeometry = desktop.availableGeometry()
print("desktop ({},{})".format(deskGeometry.width(), deskGeometry.height()))

window = QFrame()
# If you let QT pick the sizes itself, it picks dumb ones, then complains
# 'cause they are dumb
window.setMinimumSize(300, 200)
window.setMaximumSize(deskGeometry.width(), deskGeometry.height())

label = QLabel()
#call update here: no crash

caption = QLabel()
caption.setText("Hello world")

box = QVBoxLayout()
box.addWidget(label)
box.addWidget(caption)
#call update here, no crash
window.setLayout(box)
#call update here, no crash

window.show()
#this call to update results in a crash
update(label)

#window.updateGeometry()
print("App: exec")
app.exec_()
```

Output:

```
desktop (3623,2160)
Read (1515,1051)
Rotate (1051,1515)
Thumbnail(832,1200)
App: exec
```

Do I need to do anything special to tell QT that the window size will be changing?   Any suggestions for diagnosing the problem from here...

---

Update:

If I copy the body of the update function and paste it in place of the call to update, it no long crashes -- it works as expected.

From this I conclude that there is an object-lifetime issue.  Somewhere behind the scenes QT and/or Pillow is keeping a pointer to an internal buffer rather than making a copy or "stealing" the buffer.  When the object containing the buffer is deleted the pointer becomes invalid and "Bad Things Happen[TM]"

Now to determine who's being lazy...

Comment: I was going to suggest that you need to keep a reference to the underlying image data - but then I couldn't actually reproduce the problem myself. But anyway, these kinds of garbage-collection issue are well-known, so I don't think there's anything unusual going on here.

Comment: `<humor>` If I wanted object lifetime issues I'd program in c++ rather than Python -- sheesh. `</humor>'   Thanks for taking a look at the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution based on the observation mentioned in the Update that this appeared to be an object lifetime issue.

Changing the line in the `update` function from

```
pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(qimage)
```

to

```
pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(qimage).copy()
```

forces a copy of the pixmap.  This copy apparently has its own data buffer rather than borrowing the buffer from the Image.

The Label then keeps a reference to the pixmap -- ensuring the lifetime of the buffer.  The 'bug' seems to be that QPixmap.fromImage captures a pointer to the data in the Image, but does not keep a reference to the Image so if the Image gets garbage collected (which is likely 'cause it's a big object, the Label (and the pixmap) have a pointer to unallocated memory.

[This 'pointer to the buffer' stuff is sheer speculation on my part, but the bottom line is the program no longer crashes.]

Comment: I had exactly the same problem when scaling a QPixmap object, which I solved as indicated i.e. by doing a copy:
`pixmap = QPixmap("tempPic.png")`
`pixmap = pixmap.copy().scaled([...]) # before: pixmap.copy().scaled([...])`

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else stumbles upon this:

I struggled with a very similar issue and was able to solve it using slots and signals (based on [this great article](https://www.learnpyqt.com/courses/concurrent-execution/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/)) since the .copy() solution did not work for me. My solution was to separate the creation of the QPixmap and the QLabel.setPixmap into different functions. When the function that creates the QPixmap finishes, it emits a signal that triggers the function that sets the pixmap to the label.

For instance, if you wanted to use threading:

```
class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    ready = pyqtSignal()

class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, some_function, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.some_function = some_function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

        self.kwargs['ready'] = self.signals.ready

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        self.some_function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

def make_pixmap(qimage, ready, **kwargs):
    pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(qimage) # qimage is some QImage
    ready.emit()

def set_pixmap(pixmap):
    label.setPixmap(pixmap) # 'label' is some QLabel

threadpool = QThreadPool

worker = Worker(make_pixmap, image)
worker.signals.ready.connect(set_pixmap)

threadpool.start(worker)
```

Obviously using threading is not necessary in this scenario, but this is just to show that it's possible in case you want to process and show images without hanging the rest of the GUI.

Edit: The crashes came back, disregard the above. Working on another fix.